# Label that will print string on two different lines VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, label

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the printed text to the label to either 'wrap' or print half the sentence on a second line.  As it stands currently, the entire string prints on one line and covers part of a separate text box nearby

this is the code for the label that prints when a specific choice is made from the drop-down menu above

[image]

and this is the current output
[image]

Comment: You may set label property *autosize=true* or even set *autosize=false* and set it in 2-lines height at design time.

Comment: Hey @DavidBS, this didn't seem to work.  Maybe you can be more specific?

Comment: @DavidBS, You da man!  Thanks, that worked like a charm.  My apologies for not understanding you originally.  I'm good to go, thanks again!

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.  But please, vote in the right answer that I will post now - it help us to be motivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the label property autosize to false. After, set manually in the form the label length and height to display 2 or more lines.

Any text that exceed the maximum width will be automatically wrapped to the 2nd (or next) line.